# issues configuring G-WAN to use D2

Tags: d, g-wan, gdc

I've downloaded, compiled and installed gdc from it's [bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/wiki/Home).
Then I downloaded, extracted and ran G-WAN from it's [site](http://gwan.ch/download).
I can now compile D2 code using gdc and it runs fine, and I can use G-WAN to load c-script in my browser.
When I try to add a D2 script to my source folder, I can't serve them from G-WAN.

---

`sudo ./gwan`

- 'hello.d': to use D2 (*.d) scripts, install 'gdc' (sudo apt-get install gdc)`

and the program still runs and will work with other pages and c-scripts.

`./gwan`

- **linking** hello.d: undefined symbol: __data_start

and G-WAN fails to start

I don't want to `sudo apt-get install gdc` because that's a very old D1 version.

---

I'm not very strong with my linux-foo that's why I'm asking for help. It's possible that this isn't something I can fix from my end and I need to contact the server's developer.

As an aside, I tried the same thing on a fresh ubuntu vm using **dmd** and `alias gdc="dmd"` and got the exact same results, so I'm leaning towards the thought that G-WAN is configured exclusively for an older version of gdc and D1.

---

How can I configure my system to make these two applications work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue due to the implementation of GDC. The `__data_start` missing symbol is needed in PIC objects (see the [source code here](https://bitbucket.org/alexrp/gdc/src/7e22befef29c/d/phobos/internal/gc/gcgccextern.d)).

To make GDC work with G-WAN, you just have to change the GDC configuration options to support shared objects and rebuild GDC.

Comment: The D string cast policy has changed recently, see the **hello.d** example http://gwan.com/source/hello.d to see how this will affect G-WAN servlets written in D.